# Can someone verify if my proof is accurate?

Tags: limits, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

I am only allowed to use the fact that a certain sequence {${x_i}$} that is not equivalent to the zero sequence is cauchy to prove that the reciprocal {$\frac{1}{x_i}$} is also cauchy.
i.e. we know that $\forall  \epsilon > 0$, $\exists\,N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb N$ s.t. if $i, j > N_{\epsilon}$, then $|x_i - x_j| < \epsilon$
Define $\epsilon ^{,}$ s.t $\epsilon ^{,}$ = min{$\epsilon, \epsilon |x_i x_j|$}. So if we have $i, j > N_{\epsilon^{,}}$

$$|x_i - x_j| < \epsilon ^{,}$$ 
$$\implies |x_i -x_j| <  \epsilon |x_i x_j|$$ 
$$\implies \frac{|x_i -x_j|}{|x_i x_j|} <  \epsilon $$ 
$$\implies |\frac{x_i -x_j}{x_i x_j}| <  \epsilon $$ 
$$\implies |\frac{1}{x_j} - \frac{1}{x_i}| <  \epsilon $$ 
which implies that the reciprocal function is cauchy. Is my proof rigorous enough? I'm especially skeptical of this step where I chose my $\epsilon ^{,}$. It seems antithetical to the idea of limits.

Comment: Your definition of $\epsilon'$ is indeed a problem. For one thing,it cannot depend on a choice of $i$ and $j$. And if you are taking it over all pairs, you can't take a minimum (you might need the infimum) and you must prove the infimum is no zero.

Comment: $x_i, x_j$ aren't constants and you can't select an $\epsilon'$ in terms of them.

Comment: When you say it is not equivalent to the zero sequence, do you mean it does not converge to $0$?  Obviously $x_k = \frac 1k$ is Cauchy be $\frac 1{x_k} = k$ is obviously not.  But I wouldn't say $\{\frac 1k\}$ is "equivalent to the $0$ function".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thank you for your response. What should I do instead?

Comment: @fleablood That is what I mean. It does not converge to zero. There is a sense in which the {$\frac{1}{k}$} is equivalent to the zero sequence. That is the sense I am talking about.

Comment: Play with the idea that if $|x - w| < \epsilon$ then $w-\epsilon < x < w+\epsilon$ and if we assume (just for the moment) that $w-\epsilon > 0$ then $\frac 1{w+\epsilon} < \frac 1x < \frac 1{w-\epsilon}$.  Try to figure out what we have to do to get $\frac 1{w +\epsilon} \le \frac 1w - \epsilon'$ and $\frac 1{w-\epsilon} \ge \frac 1w + \epsilon'$.